# searching images on the internet by hash

Tags: image, hash, file-recovery

I have a selection of 13970 corrupted images, each named after its own MD5 hash.

Ideally I want to conjure up a tool that can search the internet matching the corrupt image with a clean undamaged version online, using this hash, and restore the image. At the moment I am trying to find a means to search online by hash.

I have been able to find online services offering hashes of images you don't want on your website for blacklisting purposes, if it is possible to check what users are posting to your website against a blacklist, it must be possible to match a corrupt image against it's original source or a repost online.

Comment: I am concerned that a corrupt image will hash to a different value from the clean original, is this not the case?

Comment: @MandyShaw: I don't think OP worded that well. OP has a file named something like `adbf5a778175ee757c34d0eba4e932bc.jpg`. The image inside has been corrupted, but the original, correct, *uncorrupted* image had an MD5 hash of `adbf5a778175ee757c34d0eba4e932bc`. OP would like to google for  `adbf5a778175ee757c34d0eba4e932bc` and have it return the uncorrupted image.

Comment: Unless there is something special about your images there's no reason for anyone to compute hashes of them, and even if they have there's no reason to post the hashes online or have them indexed by a search engine.

Comment: @James that's why I was assuming the hashing would be done at search time (and would therefore fail to match). My assumption is that the hashing in the example given by the OP is done when the blacklist check is requested. But I cannot imagine anyone going to the trouble of hashing all their images, but not going to the trouble of giving them a proper backup!

Comment: @Petro0 please clarify how you expect this to work.

Comment: @James K Polk has it spot on. The images were named after their hash before they were corrupted. So really I just have 13970 image hashes. I intend to search for these hashes to find the original image, as I can't recover the images as they are.